# ECR Image Move to ECS (Docker, Gitlab)

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, cicd

**ECR   -> ECS**

I have ECR Repository. witch automatically updated by git push command(Gitlab CI/CD).
also i have ECS cluster. i want do something like This : wen i run git push  image uploaded -> ECR after this  Uploaded -> ECS

**git push -> ECR (temp:latest) - > ECS(temp:latest)**

"git push -> ECR (temp:latest) " *-this part i have.*

"- > ECS(temp:latest)" - *this part i need*

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is a force ecs deployment to pick latest image

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster name> --service <service name> --force-new-deployment
```

If you are looking for AWS native CI/CD, try using codepipeline with ECR as source and ECS as target for deployment

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html

Comment: Hi omuthu. i  have already try this. i run this command in my local Computer. command runs successfuly but result same. image still not changed :(